# error al copilarreact con webpack y node js

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, webpack

Tengo el siguiente problema
Estoy utilizando node js y webpack para trabajar con react
Pero Quiero actualizar un state
Que recibe un valor de un input
Con la función onchange
Y que lo imprima por pantalla
Pero a la hora de ejecutar
Me dice por consola que no puede leer la propiedad setState
Que es la que utilizo para actualizar el state
Alguna solución.
Tengo nodejs y claro utilizo webpack para copilar react y jsx por qué la combinó para crear una api.

```
el error que me arroja  en consola:
***Uncaught ReferenceError: setState is not defined
    at handleChange (bundles.js:18995)***
```

este seria mi codigo

```
***import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../style/style.css';
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { items: [], text: null };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange;

      }
      handleChange(e) {
     setState({text : e.target.value});
        console.log(e.target.value);
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" id ='input-usuario'  onChange={this.handleChange}  value={this.state.text} className="form-control" placeholder="usuario" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></input><br></br>
  <input type="password" id ='input-contraseña' onChange={this.handleChange} value = {this.state.text} className="form-control" placeholder="usuario" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></input>
</div>
            </div> 
        )
    }
}
export default App;***
```

Comment: te falta el `this`, para que sea `this.setState()`

Comment: no amigo, la agregue y nada sigue con el mismo error